# How to validate textbox when selecting radiobutton in jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have radio-button, so I want to validate the Textbox when a user selects radio button. Must prompt a user to insert the details as validated by radio-button. e.g Radio-button (EmailAddress).

Let me share the logic below for clarity. The message for email must be this one `Example: lsmith@myschool.edu, mfoster@myschool.edu`. I want to know the JQuery side of validating any of these radio button when a user select them and need some help.

```
  <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CourseAdmin.EmailAddress, "EmailAddress")
                                    <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-form-label">EmailAddress</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CourseAdmin.LoginID, "LoginID")
                                    <label for="LoginID" class="col-form-label">LoginID</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CourseAdmin.SIS_ID, "SIS_ID")
                                    <label for="SIS_ID" class="col-form-label">SIS_ID</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.eNtsaAdmin.eNtsaTextAreaDisc, new { @class = "form-control", style = "font-size: medium; font-weight: bold; width:450px" })

                                </div>
                                <hr />


                            </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id="btnNext">
                                    Next
                                </button>
                            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        // Fire when radio button clicked  
        $("#LoginID, #SIS_ID").bind("change", function () {  
            checkdata();  
        });  
  
        // Fire when we enter anything in the textbox  
        $("#eNtsaTextAreaDisc").bind("input", function () {  
            checkdata();  
        });  
    });  
  
    //here we check both radio button clicked and textbox filled with some information  
    function checkdata() {  
        if ($("#LoginID").prop("checked") && $("#SIS_ID").prop("checked") && $("#eNtsaTextAreaDisc").val().length > 0) {  
            $("#btnNext").removeAttr("disabled");  
        }  
        else {  
            $("#btnNext").attr("disabled","disabled");  
        }  
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: For us to give you good jQuery help, please post a [mcve] with PURE HTML and Script. There is NOTHING relevant to C# in this question. Please click edit, then `[<>]` and post relevant RENDERED HTML and add the relevant bootstrap and jQuery libraries

Comment: Do you mean that the validation rule for the textbox will change depending on which radio button is selected? It wasn't quite clear. Confusingly, you gave an example about emails,  but none of the code you've shown appears to  relate to emails.

Comment: @Adyson please have a look at my javascript code, need some help. the issue now is my radio button they all become selected. I dont want this to happened its bad for user experience.

Comment: Unrelated: `.bind()` in jQuery has been deprecated for many years. You should be using `.on()` instead. See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) for this information.

Comment: Also to set _properties_ such as "disabled", you should really be using `.prop()`, instead of `.attr()` and `removeAttr()`. Again, this is mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: "my radio button they all become selected"...because you haven't grouped them. Radio buttons have to be in a group in order for selecting one of them to un-select the other one. You seem to have bound yours to separate properties in your model. If they are meant to be options where only one can be chosen, then this makes no sense. Consider how you'd do it if it was a dropdownlist (which gives the same functionality just with a different UI).

Comment: For example, this article shows simply how to create a radio button list in a single group bound to a single model property: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/radiobutton-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @Adyson they are group as form, have a look again closely.

Comment: You mean `form-group`? That's just a visual thing (powered by Bootstrap, I assume).  It's irrelevant. It's not defining an actual radio button group which the browser will use to determine that the radio buttons are mutually exclusive. For that, they all must have the same `name` attribute. In Razor, you make that happen by binding them all to the same model property, and then the RadioButtonFor() helper will take care of the rest. Seriously, take a look at the link I posted just above. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio for how it's done in raw HTML